# Adding a custom field to the sign-in in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I tried adding to the user model :

attr_accessible :client_version

add added column client_version to the DB using the migration

In the sign_in request I've added the field:

addParameter("user[client_version]", clientVersion);

I also tried to tweak the trackable module But that does not work, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to override the default Devise views, you will first need to run:

`rails generate devise:views`

from your terminal. This will give you access to all of the views that Devise uses at `app/views/devise`. You can then add any additional fields to `sessions/new.html.erb` that you need.

Comment: 10x, What about when connecting using Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Override the sign up form view and add your field to it. You can detect the client and prefill in the field.

Comment: sorry, I mean sign-in, not sign-up.